# Use JavaScript to grade user response (compare two arrays)

Tags: javascript, arrays, diff

I am working on a script to grade a user response by comparing two arrays. (It is a quiz to see how well they know information word-for-word.) I already have some of the code that I need, like making the user response lowercase and splitting it. All I need is something to find the number of differences/mistakes. For example:

```
var correctanswer = ["The","quick","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dog"];
var useranswer = ["The","brown","fox","jumped","up","and","over","the","really","lazy","cat"];
alert(counterrors(correctanswer, useranswer));
```

In this particular example, running the function I'm looking for would return that the user made 5 errors (they **omitted** "quick", **added** "up", "and", and "really", and **changed** "dog" to "cat"). As you can see, the two arrays may be of different lengths.

Does anybody know how to approach this? I was thinking it would probably be a loop like:

```
for (x in correctanswer) {
    // compare correctanswer[x] to useranswer[x]... not sure how exactly. Seems tricky...
}
```

Thank you for looking at this! I have seen John Resig's diff solution (http://ejohn.org/projects/javascript-diff-algorithm/) and other similar things, and even a few array comparisons, but nothing seemed to work since the ones I found return all the differences, whereas I want to see how many differences there are. Again, thanks for looking and please let me know of any questions.

**Update:** Many thanks to Magnar for the answer! It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are after is the [The Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of the two arrays.

It is an algorithm that calculates the number of *additions*, *deletions* and *substitutions* necessary to transform one sequence into another.

The [Wikipedia page I linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) has a pseudo-code implementation. I have done a line-for-line translation to JavaScript for you:

```
var correctanswer = ["The","quick","brown","fox","jumped","over","the","lazy","dog"];
var useranswer =    ["The","brown","fox","jumped","up","and","over","the","really","lazy","cat"];

console.log(calculate_levenshtein_distance(correctanswer, useranswer));

function calculate_levenshtein_distance(s, t) {
  var m = s.length + 1, n = t.length + 1;
  var i, j;

  // for all i and j, d[i,j] will hold the Levenshtein distance between
  // the first i words of s and the first j words of t;
  // note that d has (m+1)x(n+1) values
  var d = [];

  for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
    d[i] = [i]; // the distance of any first array to an empty second array
  }
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    d[0][j] = j; // the distance of any second array to an empty first array
  }

  for (j = 1; j < n; j++) {
    for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
      if (s[i - 1] === t[j - 1]) {
        d[i][j] = d[i-1][j-1];           // no operation required
      } else {
        d[i][j] = Math.min(
                    d[i - 1][j] + 1,     // a deletion
                    d[i][j - 1] + 1,     // an insertion
                    d[i - 1][j - 1] + 1  // a substitution
                  );
      }
    }
  }

  return d[m - 1][n - 1];
}
```

This will log `5` to the console. Which is, as you'll see, the correct distance between the arrays. The student didn't add `lazy`. So it's 1 deletion, 3 additions and 1 substitutions.

Comment: Magnar - Thanks! I think this is it... So would I pass the array values instead of the strings like they did in the article?

Comment: Yes, instead of chars you would use the array values; the words.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'm not too good with JavaScript yet, but I will try to take it from here. If you have any suggestions on how to implement, please let me know. I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: I translated the wikipedia pseudocode into JavaScript for you. :-)

Comment: Thanks. And I updated the main post because (like you said) there are 5 errors, not 6. Your function ran faster in FF than the one I found before (http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/6942).

Comment: Please note that I've upgraded the code with a bugfix. The previous version did not look at the first word in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understand what you want but I think this is the solution.

```
function counterrors(a, b) {
    var max = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
    var min = Math.min(a.length, b.length);
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < min; i+=1) {
        if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }
    return count + max - min;  // max - min for any extra things that don't match
}
var correctanswer = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog"];
var useranswer = ["The", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "up", "and", "over", "the", "really", "lazy", "cat"];
alert(counterrors(correctanswer, useranswer));
```

Comment: John - Thanks for sharing. I just tried that and it calculated 10 errors instead of 6...

Comment: 10 is the correct value if they need to type the words in that order.  Are you trying to find out how many words the user did not type which is in the answer? I think Magnar has the solution you are looking for.

Comment: I'm trying to find the number of additions plus deletions plus word variations (like swapping "dog" with "cat"). So not just what they didn't type but also the incorrect things they did type... Any other ideas? EDIT: Just saw Magnar's answer.